# find_by() returns nil when database has the record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

SOLVED: Turns out I had the wrong Database open in MySQL... and I was using the wrong key (someone posted an answer saying the row wasn't in my database. but then they deleted it, if you want to post it again ill accept)

For some reason .find_by() is returning nil when a record exists that should be returned. I can confirm that the record exists in the DB using .all() I can also confirm the SQL is returning a row when i run it manually in a MySQL prompt.

Ive checked for a default scope on the Institutions model and there is none.

Heres the output from my debugger and a test database:

```
0> Institution.all
  Institution Load (1.5ms)  SELECT `institutions`.* FROM `institutions`
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Institution id: 1, institution_name: "Example Inc.", customer_id: nil, address1: "xxxxxxxx", address2: "", city: "Detroit", zip: "xxxxx", region: "Michigan", country: "United States", zoho_customer_id: nil, lms_id: nil, last_billed_at: nil, lti_key: "3--4a9c711efad7d997d3b2145a2efa14a30d9e91df5bc02f5...", lti_secret: "d439358b8e38e95cb70e", custom_registration: nil, staging: false, lti_return_url: nil, domain: nil, first_name: "xxxxx", last_name: "xxxxxx", email: "xxxxxxx@example.com", phone: nil, uuid: "1ce1f720-5cc7-4abd-9ff5-6a968c1cbd73", standalone: true, logo_url: nil, hex_color_one: "000000", hex_color_two: "FFFFFF", lms_name: "none", slug: nil, created_at: "2016-04-13 15:55:01", updated_at: "2016-04-13 15:55:01", large_logo_url: nil, student_access_after_course: true, no_discussion: false, no_messaging: false, support_email: nil, no_print_and_download: true>]>

0> Institution.where(lti_key: request_key)
  Institution Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `institutions`.* FROM `institutions`  WHERE `institutions`.`lti_key` = '3--5ac4090c6facdc5b795f64da9b70a5351cb60e86a301a820d94a83f8d055878d'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

0> Institution.all
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `institutions`.* FROM `institutions`
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Institution id: 1, institution_name: "Example Inc.", customer_id: nil, address1: "xxxxxxx", address2: "", city: "Detroit", zip: "xxxxx", region: "Michigan", country: "United States", zoho_customer_id: nil, lms_id: nil, last_billed_at: nil, lti_key: "3--4a9c711efad7d997d3b2145a2efa14a30d9e91df5bc02f5...", lti_secret: "d439358b8e38e95cb70e", custom_registration: nil, staging: false, lti_return_url: nil, domain: nil, first_name: "xxxxxx", last_name: "xxxxxx", email: "xxxxxx@example.com", phone: nil, uuid: "1ce1f720-5cc7-4abd-9ff5-6a968c1cbd73", standalone: true, logo_url: nil, hex_color_one: "000000", hex_color_two: "FFFFFF", lms_name: "none", slug: nil, created_at: "2016-04-13 15:55:01", updated_at: "2016-04-13 15:55:01", large_logo_url: nil, student_access_after_course: true, no_discussion: false, no_messaging: false, support_email: nil, no_print_and_download: true>]>

0> Institution.all.first
  Institution Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `institutions`.* FROM `institutions`   ORDER BY `institutions`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Institution id: 1, institution_name: "Example Inc.", customer_id: nil, address1: "xxxxxxx", address2: "", city: "Detroit", zip: "xxxxx", region: "Michigan", country: "United States", zoho_customer_id: nil, lms_id: nil, last_billed_at: nil, lti_key: "3--4a9c711efad7d997d3b2145a2efa14a30d9e91df5bc02f5...", lti_secret: "d439358b8e38e95cb70e", custom_registration: nil, staging: false, lti_return_url: nil, domain: nil, first_name: "xxxxxx", last_name: "xxxxxxx", email: "xxxxxxxx@example.com", phone: nil, uuid: "1ce1f720-5cc7-4abd-9ff5-6a968c1cbd73", standalone: true, logo_url: nil, hex_color_one: "000000", hex_color_two: "FFFFFF", lms_name: "none", slug: nil, created_at: "2016-04-13 15:55:01", updated_at: "2016-04-13 15:55:01", large_logo_url: nil, student_access_after_course: true, no_discussion: false, no_messaging: false, support_email: nil, no_print_and_download: true>

0> request_key
=> "3--5ac4090c6facdc5b795f64da9b70a5351cb60e86a301a820d94a83f8d055878d"

0> Institution.find_by( lti_key: request_key )
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  `institutions`.* FROM `institutions`  WHERE `institutions`.`lti_key` = '3--5ac4090c6facdc5b795f64da9b70a5351cb60e86a301a820d94a83f8d055878d' LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

Once again, if I run this query manually I get the appropriate row.....

```
SELECT  `institutions`.* FROM `institutions`  WHERE `institutions`.`lti_key` = '3--5ac4090c6facdc5b795f64da9b70a5351cb60e86a301a820d94a83f8d055878d' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have not exectly this record in database since your `Institution.where(lti_key: request_key)` returns empty relation.

`Institution.all.first` just returns first record from database without any condition.

Answer (score 3):

You are requesting `"3--5ac4090c6facdc5b795f64da9b70a5351cb60e86a301a820d94a83f8d0558..."` And the row is `"3--4a9c711efad7d997d3b2145a2efa14a30d9e91df5bc02f5..."`